Can we make a button stay still when you move your screen around or scroll up/down on a tablet?
This code work well on a traditional computer with non-touch screen.
`<style>
    #stayFixedDiv{
      background-color: #FBD603;
      position: fixed;
      left: 40px;
    }
    </style>

    <body>
    <div id ="stayFixedDiv">
     <a   style="font-size: 35px; text-decoration: none" > Pause Video</a>
    </div>

    </body>
`

But that code does not work on a tablet. When I move the screen on my tablet around, the button doesn't stay still as on my desktop.
How can we achieve that?

that because the address bar will hide and as such the viewport gets bigger. Try to set it fixed to bottom.

If you set a bottom or top property it will work better because bottom or top property changes every time you change the screen size. Heres a test:


#stayFixedDiv{
      background-color: #FBD603;
      position: fixed;
      left: 40px;
      bottom: 100px;
    }
<body>
    <div id ="stayFixedDiv">
     <a   style="font-size: 35px; text-decoration: none" > Pause Video</a>
    </div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>some paragraph
<br>
<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>some paragraph of something
<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>more paragraph
<br>
<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </body>
`




It does not work properly on a tablet. Every time I move the screen up/ down, it disappear although sometimes it appears

I know the problem. Actually, it works if I don't magnify the screen. If I do, then the  can not see the button
